# How to call shortcode in non-wordpress pages?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, shortcode, wordpress-shortcode

I'm currently working (on my localhost) on a new wordpress page which uses various shortcodes from a plugin. When I create a page within the wordpress dashboard and insert a shortcode in the HTML edit it works fine.

However, I have now created a new page from scratch (home.php), which I want to use as my start page and I want to call one of the shortcodes and it doesnt work. When I insert just the shortcode in html [the_shortcode] the file just returns this as text output. When I use

```
<?php echo do_shortcode(‘[the_shortcode]’); ?>
```

the page show not output.

I'm fairly new to shortcodes, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Does the file perhaps need to sit in a specific folder to be able to call shortcodes or needs some importing of files?

With regards to folder locations I have tried both:

```
C:\MAMP\htdocs\newwordpresspage
C:\MAMP\htdocs\newwordpresspage\wp-content\themes\newtheme
```

and then called the file via my localhost address.

Could anyone please help how to successfully call the shortcodes?

```
<?php 
define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', false ); 
require( './wp-load.php' );
echo do_shortcode('[gd_advanced_search]'); 
?>
```

Comment: non wp pages? you want to access the wp features outside wp?

Comment: I meant with that that the php file I created from scratch in Atom was not created in the wp dashboard, but of course it lies within the wp folder (see root in original post)

Comment: I just tested, your code works. The PHP file has to be in the WP root folder (same level as `wp-load.php`).

Answer (score 0):

In php template/theme file you should use.

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[the_shortcode]'); ?>
```

Comment: I did! I just noticed that it was deleted from my original post, probably because I didnt wrap it in the right format - see again pls, I updated

Comment: I noticed that you have put  " ‘ " at place of  "  ' "  in your shortcode function . Please copy and paste  line  from my answer.

Comment: For a second I hoped that would be it, but it didnt have any effect. I have again tried and saved the file in both locations and opened it via my localhost address. The odd thing is also that when i look at the source code (when I load the page) the code stops where the php line is inserted. Would you have any other solution idea? Thank you vey much for helping!!

Comment: I think now your shortcode is working. Can you check  "the_shortcode" which I think you have defined in functions.php  . May be there is any error in the function.

Comment: the shortcode itself is fine, because when I create a new page via the wordpress dashboard and edit the html code to insert the shortcode it works fine, i.e. it runs the function. However, I dont want to create a page there (which is only for blog entries or content in general). Do I have to save the php page in a specific location or include anything specific in the php file? I'm losing my mind with this ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', false );
require( './wp-load.php' );
```

add these lines in your **home.php** now you are able to use all WordPress functions in your file.

Following one is working fine for me
I created a shortcode `test_code` and using this [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/shortcoder/)
**[sc name="test_code"]**

```
<?php 
define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', false ); 
require( './wp-load.php' );
echo do_shortcode('[sc test_code]'); 
?>
```

Comment: Thank you! I amended the php to include this (see EDIT 1 in original post) but it didnt change anything. Does the file maybe need to sit in a specific folder?

Comment: check my answer i think you need to add prefix of that plugin which you used to create shortcode

Comment: The shortcodes from the plugin should not require any prefix (also I wouldnt know which ones), see https://wpgeodirectory.com/docs/core-shortcodes/ Shame, I cant get it to work. Is there anything else we could try?

Comment: Did you fixed the issue?